# Is $\mathcal{B}_a$ non empty?

Tags: general-topology

I'm having trouble understanding exactly what the basis for a system of neighborhoods is, so I thought asking this question might help me understand.

> if $a\in X$ and X is a metric space, is $\mathcal{B}_a$  always nonempty?

Please prove it, and also, if you can explain what $\mathcal{B}_a$ is in an intuitive way, that would be appreciated. However, I'm really just looking for a proof.

$\mathcal{B}_a$ is the basis for the system of neighborhoods at a.

Comment: Define $\mathcal{B}_a$ for us, please.

Comment: If you define a topology via bases of neighborhoods systems, then the $\cal B_a$ are required to be non-empty. If the topology is given, and $\cal B_a$ is any neighborhood basis, then there is at least one neighborhood of $a$, namely $X$, and this $X$ contains an element from $\cal B_a$, so $\cal B_a$ cannot be empty.

Comment: Is there only one $\mathcal{B}_a$ or can there be more than one?

Comment: There can be more than one (in fact "usually" there are infinitely many). For example if $a \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is any positive real sequence for which $\lim{s}=\infty$, then $\mathcal{B}_s=\{\text{open balls of radius $\frac{1}{s_n}$ and center $a$}\}$ will be a neighborhood basis for $a$.

Answer (score 0):

A basis for the system of neighborhoods at $a$ (here denoted by $\mathcal{B}_a$) is a collection of neighborhoods of $a$ (sometimes restricted to open neighborhoods), such that each neighborhood of $a $ contains at least one element of $\mathcal{B_a}$ as a subset.

Right now I can't think of any intuitive ways of explaining it (maybe drawing a picture of what the definition says could help), but here's a link that might be of use: [Definition of Basis for the Neighborhood System](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139624/definition-of-basis-for-the-neighborhood-system)

As for your question, the answer is affirmative, since (as was written in the comments) in any topological space there is at least one neighborhood of any point (the space itself), and so $\mathcal{B_a}$ must have an element that is a subset of this neighborhood, hence it cannot by empty.