# Continuity over Basis for the neighborhood

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm trying to solve the following exercise:

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a function from a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$. Let $a \in X$ and let $B_{f(a)}$ be a basis for the neighborhood system at $f(a)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if for each $N \in B_{f(a)}, f^{-1}(N)$ is a neighborhood of $a$.

To explain my problem with this exercise, consider this example: let $X$ and $Y$ be the space of real numbers, and choose as basis for the neighborhood system the following collection:
$ B_{f(a)} = \{ \{f(a) \pm \frac{1}{n} : n \in  \mathbb{N}, n > m\},  m \in \mathbb{N} \}$.
If I consider this basis, it's not true that an element of $ B_{f(a)}$ is mapped in a neighborhood of $a$, instead, it will be mapped (i think) in some element of a basis for the neighborhood system at $a$. That's because an element of the basis $ B_{f(a)}$ is not a neighborhood of $f(a)$, as it does not contain an open ball centered in $f(a)$. Where am I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If some element of your candidate $B_{f(a)}$ is not a neighborhood of $f(a)$, then $B_{f(a)}$ cannot be a basis for the neighborhood system at $f(a)$.

Comment: Write down the definition of a basis for the neighborhood system at $y \in Y$ and check whether your collection is a basis at $f(a)$. As you say, the elements of the collection $B_{f(a)}$ are  no neighborhoods of $f(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments,
as you pointed out, my $B_{f(a)}$ is not made of neighborhoods. somewhat embarrassing being not able to read correctly the definition of basis, which requires that it's elements must be also neighboorhoods.

[Definition 4.9](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139624/definition-of-basis-for-the-neighborhood-system) - Let $a$ be a point in metric space $X$. A collection of neighborhoods $B_a$ is called a basis for the neighborhood system at a if every neighborhood $N$ of a contains some element $B$ in $B_a$.